# Mean Value Theorem to show inequalities about numbers

Tags: calculus

> Show $\sqrt{65}-8=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{c}}$ for some $c \in (64,65)$, and hence show: 
>   $$8+\frac{1}{18}<\sqrt{65}<8+\frac{1}{16}$$

I managed to do the first part easily, but I don't know how to do the "hence show" part.

*Working For the First Part:*

Consider the function $f(x)=x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ on $[64,65]$. Then f is continuous on $[64,65]$ and differentiable on $(64,65)$. By the mean value theorem, there is a $c \in (64,65)$ such that:
$$f'(c)=\frac{f(65)-f(64)}{65-64}$$
$f'(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$, so we have:
$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{c}}=\sqrt{65}-8$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write it like $$ \sqrt{65} = 8 + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{c}}.$$ Since $64 < c < 65$ you have $8 = \sqrt{64} < \sqrt{c} < \sqrt{65} < \sqrt{81} = 9$ so that $$\frac{1}{2 \cdot 9} < \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{c}} < \frac{1}{2 \cdot 8}.$$ Now add $8$.

Answer (score 0):

The first part looks good.

From the first part we know, that there exists a $c \in (64, 65)$, such that 
$$\sqrt{65} = 8 + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{c}} \; .$$
Since $64 < c < 81$ and the square root is a monotone function, we see that $$8 < \sqrt{c} < 9 \; .$$ 
From this it follows that 
$$ \frac{1}{18} = \frac{1}{2\cdot 9} < \frac{1}{2\sqrt{c}} < \frac{1}{2\cdot 8} = \frac{1}{16} \; ,$$
so by adding $8$ we get 
$$ 8 + \frac{1}{18} < \underbrace{8 + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{c}}}_{= \sqrt{65}} < 8 + \frac{1}{16} \; .$$

Answer (score 0):

$64\lt c\lt 65$ $\Rightarrow$ $8\lt\sqrt{c}\lt9$ $\Rightarrow$ $1/18 \lt 1/2\sqrt{c}\lt 1/16$.

Since $(1/2\sqrt{c}) + 8=\sqrt{65}$ as you proved, you can easily see that

$8+(1/18)\lt\sqrt{65}\lt 8 + (1/16)$.